# Empty page after installing Angular Playground into an Ionic 4 project

Tags: angular, sass, ionic4

I have a basic Ionic 4 project created with Ionic CLI. I've then added and ran Angular Playground with the following command:

```
ng add angular-playground
```

After that I have fixed the path for the styles to be like for the main project in `angular.json`:

```
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
  },
  {
    "input": "src/global.scss"
  }
],
```

Now, when I run `npm run playground` and navigate to the `http://localhost:4201` in a browser I can only see a blank page. There are no compilation or browser console errors whatsoever.

Why can't I see anything on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in a rule coming from Ionic stylesheets you've included as part of the `global.scss`. If you inspect the `body` element in browser you'll see it has the following rule attached to it:

```css
html:not(.hydrated) body {
    display: none;
}
```

This is a rule related to [hydration](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web) which serves no purpose when using Angular Playground so it can simply be overridden by adding a third stylesheet as `src/playground.scss` with the following content:

```css
html:not(.hydrated) body {
  display: block;
}
```

Then add this on top of the ones already in `angular.json` for the Playground project:

```
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
  },
  {
    "input": "src/global.scss"
  },
  {
    "input": "src/playground.scss"
  }
],
```

Now, if you restart the `npm run playground` it should render the normal Playground page with component selector.

I've also covered this more thoroughly in [a blog post](https://roope.tech/2019/11/19/getting-ionic-4-to-work-with-the-angular-playground/).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `.hydrated` rule below:

```
html:not(.hydrated) body {
    display: none;
}
```

was added because the ionic module was missing in the top-most app.module.ts, leading to a blank screen.

To fix this, make sure you properly import the `IonicModule` in your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular'; // import the ionic module from here

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,

        IonicModule.forRoot() // import IonicModule forRoot()

    ],
    providers: [
        AppAuthGuard
    ],
    exports: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```